# jQuery mobile collapsible div not styling correctly

Tags: jquery, coding-style, mobile

Using this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> 
    <title>Page Title</title> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0b3/jquery.mobile-1.0b3.min.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0b3/jquery.mobile-1.0b3.min.js">    </script>
</head> 
<body> 

<div data-role="collapsible" data-theme="a" data-content-theme="a">
   <h3>Header swatch A</h3>
   <p>I'm the collapsible content with a themed content block set to "A".</p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I find that the expanding collapsible does not have the theme styling expected - in fact it has none. On viewing the source of the page and comparing it will the example page on jQuery mobile (http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/content/content-collapsible.html) it appears that the following classes are missing from dynamically created div that wraps around the expanding paragraph below the header within the collapsible:

```
ui-btn-up-a ui-corner-bottom
```

The code running the example page is their own internal code and not the same as is used for deployment so I'm guessing there is something in theirs that is not in the beta release that dynamically creates the classes.

The question is whether anybody knows what the error is and how to solve this?

Comment: Have a look on the page http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/content/content-collapsible.html under the header "Theming Collapsible Headers" you can see what I want to acheive, the content is themed with a nice rounded border at the bottom so it appears in a block with the header from which it expands. It does this by having the class "ui-btn-up-a" on the wrapping div which is created by the js and not part of the core html code. When I try to replicate this the "ui-btn-up-a" is not applied to the wrapping div, hence the lack of styling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay the answer is: "Theming collapsible content requires jquery 1.6.4"

The referenced version is in the log for the rc1 release which was posted two days after I posted the above problem.

I was using an older version, viewing the source on the jquery example page this wasn't obvious as there is no version control reference immediately apparant just:

```
<script src="../../js/jquery.js"></script>
```

I'm not sure who would vote up the image path solution offered by Mike as being an answer to this question as it doesn't answer the question posted.

So if you upgrade your jq mobile you will need to upgrade your jquery to take advantage of what's on offer.

Answer (score 1):

The Google code CSS file has relative references to images.

```
url(images/icons-18-white.png);
```

That's rarely helpful. Try hosting the CSS file locally and changing the references to match your file structure. Also, unless you're using firebug to view source, you won't see the classes. Using a browser's "View Source" option shows you the code **delivered by the server**, not the code created by javascript.

**Update:** Just did a copy / paste locally, and everything works fine. So it's not the code, gotta be something with your setup.

**Update 2:** Looking at your question, I realized you want the -content- to be themed. If you need that, you have to assign a data-role="content" to the content.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the input but the issue isn't the style paths. The header of the collapsible is styled fine, icons all present etc it is the contents of the collapsible that is missing any formatting. If I use firebug and remove the classes from the jQuery mobile site the styles also disappear so I'm pretty sure it is a case of the dynamically created wrapping div not having all the classes required to format the themed appearance. If you use the code above and replace the style sheet as described is the whole of the collapsible styled or just the header with the + - icon?

Comment: In fact I can use Firebug to edit the html and add ui-btn-up-a to the class and it changes to look as I want it.

Comment: Hrm, ok I will look into this more later. Just a quick FYI, Google isn't going to host that beta code forever (something I just learned the hard way with beta 2), so make sure you have a backup plan when they pull it.

Comment: Thanks Mike, that still doesn't work. If I add data-role="content" data-theme="a" data-content-theme="a" to the p tag it will style like the header but it is not grouped as per the example on the jQuery mobile site linked to in the question. Nor do they use any data tags on the content elements in the examples shown either.